# how to fix element-icons.woff and .ttf in node_modules is error

Tags: css, vue.js, fonts

**I have got this two error.**

How to fix this error.

Failed to compile with 2 errors

These dependencies were not found:

fonts/element-icons.ttf in ./node_modules/css-loader??ref--3-oneOf-1-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??ref--3-oneOf-1-2!./node_modules/element-ui/lib/theme-chalk/index.css

fonts/element-icons.woff in ./node_modules/css-loader??ref--3-oneOf-1-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??ref--3-oneOf-1-2!./node_modules/element-ui/lib/theme-chalk/index.css

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to show your dependencies file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `yarn install`
delete node_modules
Try to install with `npm install`